# Выдаёт ошибку когда пытаюсь прочитать 2й файл(fstream)

Tags: c++, fstream

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string> // Для строчек
#include <fstream> // Для файлов

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int otvet;
string v;
string o;
   ifstream file("D:\\vvod.txt");
   getline(file, v);
   file.close();
   cout<< v<< endl;
   ifstream file("D:\\otvet.txt");
   getline(file, o);

   return 0;
}
```

"error: redeclaration of 'std::ifstream file" Компилятор выдаёт эту ошибку когда пытаюсь прочитать 2-й файл

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы так пишете, как будто ошибка уже при работе программы :)

Ошибка у вас потому, что вы объявляете в одной области видимости две переменные с одним именем - `file`.

Дайте переменной для работы со вторым файлом другое имя...